# PrestaShop 1.7, Admin back office product combinations attributes are not showing up

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I've set up the new PrestaShop 1.7 and imported my custom theme from the localhost. In localhost, everything is working fine but in a development server I am having an issue.

Admin - Product - Combinations, attributes are not showing up.

I am able to select only the color attribute. I have created other attributes, it's displaying in attributes and features

Attributes Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFWT1.png

Products combination screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws8I6.png

Comment: I think there is no way for anyone here to know the cause, first point, you need to be sure that your server is compatible with PS 1.7 and it meets the minimum requirements, you are warned on this in the installation.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the same page on your localhost installation?